# Height of full binary tree

Tags: binary-tree, layer, logarithm, exponential

I just need confirmation that i´m right:
A binary tree with 'e' layers has

> (2^e)-1

elements.
The other way around: A binary tree with 'n' elements has

> log2(n+1)

layers...

Am i right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you describe the 'height' of your tree. Generally, a tree with only one element is said to be at height 0. The calculations are like this:

The number of leaves in a full binary tree of height n is 2^n. The number of interior nodes in a full binary tree of height n is 2^n - 1.

So a full binary tree with n layers will have a total of (2^n + 2^n - 1) elements. That turns out to be (2*2^n - 1) or simply 2^(n+1) - 1 elements.

The other way around, a binary tree with n elements has a height of log2(n+1) - 1.

Comment: (2^n + 2^n - 1), (2*2^n - 1), 2^(n+1) -1 ist not the same i think.
However (2^n + 2^n - 1) was on answer i was looking for ty!
Let´s say we want to count the number of layers n (root node is layer 1...), then my formula would be right, wouldn´t it?

Comment: (2^n + 2^n - 1); (2*2^n - 1); 2^(n+1) -1 are all equivalent. And yes, if the root node is layer 1 then your formula is correct. But generally, the root node is layer 0.

Comment: I don't get how your formulas can be equivalent! Let's say n=2, then the first formula = 6 the second = 4 and the third = 7

Comment: if n = 2 then, (1) (2^n + 2^n - 1) = (2^2 + 2^2 - 1) = 4 + 4 - 1 = 7
(2) (2*2^n - 1) = (2*2^2 - 1) = (2*4 - 1) = 8 - 1 = 7

Comment: Sorry I apologize. I thought the -n was part of the exponent! Ty